# React.js: react on changes in external object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After reading official **react.js** documentation I understand how it should work in a good way, like

1. I have list of items in initial component state
2. adding new item through **setState** will update state and trigger update of UI

What should I do if I use external object as model like some global array which should be available for some not **react.js** parts of code OR could be modified with web sockets somewhere in future? Is calling **ReactDOM.render** after each action a good way? AFAIK it should work ok from performance point of view.

Comment: the render method of the component is called each time it's `state` changes

Comment: So if I change state by myself (state - I mean any object, not react.js state) and trigger ReactDOM.render for component - there is no difference, right?

Comment: I can't say exactly the performance overhead you'll get by calling ReactDOM.render every time your data changes, but seems like overkill and is not the way react docs recommend doing things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still use `setState`:

```
let React = require('React');
let externalThing = require('tools/vendor/whoever/external-lib');

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
  }
  getInitialState() {
    // This assumes your external thing is written by someone who was
    // smart enough to not allow direct manipulation (because JS has
    // no way to monitor primitives for changes), and made sure
    // to offer API functions that allow for event handling etc.
    externalThing.registerChangeListener(() => this.updateBasedOnChanges(externalThing));
    return { data: externalThing.data }        
  }
  updateBasedOnChanges(externalThing) {
    // note that setState does NOT automatically trigger render(),
    // because React is smarter than that. It will only trigger
    // render() if it sees that this new 'data' is different
    // (either by being a different thing entirely, or having
    // different content)
    this.setState({
      data: externalThing.data
    });
  }
  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If the external thing you're using is terribly written and you have to manipulate its data directly, your first step is to write an API for it so you *don't* directly manipulate that data.

```
let externalData = require('externaldata') // example: this is a shared array
let ExternalDataAPI = new ExternalDataAPI(externalData);
...
```

And then you make sure that API has all the update and event hooks:

```
class ExternalDataAPI {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.listeners = [];
  }
  addListener(fn) {
    this.listeners.push(fn);
  }
  update(...) {
    // do something with data
    this.listeners.forEach(fn => fn());
  }
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, there are frameworks that already do this for you (flux, etc) but they also somewhat dictate how many more things "should be done" so that might be overkill for your need.

Comment: It's an ok answer, but I think the judgmental parts about "data manipulation" are not called for and not accurate. First, in this use case, the `externalThing` can be anything, maybe just an object maintained by some other aspects of the code or some other library, who said anything about an API? Secondly, this is not about data manipulation from within react? Maybe it's just something we want to plug into our app - we just need it's data and we cannot really change the way it is or how that data is changed/maintained. So if there's no easy approach to do this in react, why not just admit it?

Comment: Or maybe it's an excellent idea to write a generic example with an assumption clearly indicated as such, using lots and lots of code comments to make that clear, to show how easy it is. An API is just an application programming interfact: it doesn't matter if that's just an object, or a library, or a networked service, or any other thing folks come up with that access the data they need, and be notified of changes to that data.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is about organizing your code in a manageable way, I would first of all suggest pairing ReactJS with a Flux-type framework, like Redux or Relay.

If you want to skip that for now, then you can organize your project using some react components at the top of the hierarchy for storing and retrieving data. For example, in such a component, in its [componentWillMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) method, you can start a `setTimeout` that periodically checks your global array and calls `setState` when appropriate. The render method should then contain child components that receive this state as props.

Below is an example. Obviously, the timers can be replaced by whichever method you use to subscribe to your data changes.

```js
// your global object
var globalState = {name: "Sherlock Holmes"}

function onData(callback) {
  setInterval(function(){
    callback(globalState)
  }, 1500)
}

var Child = React.createClass({  
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});

var Root = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() { 
    return {} 
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
   var that = this;
    this.props.onData(function(data){
     that.setState({external: data})
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    if (this.state.external)
     return <Child name={this.state.external.name}/>
    else
     return <div>loading...</div>;
  }
});


ReactDOM
.render(<Root onData={onData} />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: it's worth noting that this is going to run through babel already anyway, so using ES6 would make a lot of sense: no `that=this; function() { that.setState...`, just use context-preserving arrow functions: `this.props.onData(data => this.setState({external: data}))`